# What does ensemble-based model of enzyme mean?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, enzymes, biotechnology

I am reading [Pan et al. (2000)](http://www.pnas.org/content/97/22/12020.short), a paper about dihydrofolate reductase (DHFR).  They claim using a ensemble-based model of DHFR.

What is a **ensemble-based model**?

Comment: Can you please link to the paper? Does DHFR means "Dihydrofolate reductase"?

Comment: @Remi.b,yes it is dihydrofolate reductase, I edited the question to add the link

Answer (score 1):

An 'ensemble' is a set of related models of a structure.

For example, [conformational ensembles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformational_ensembles) describe the structure of flexible proteins. There is a database of such structures here : http://pedb.vib.be/.

When NMR is used to determine a structure, the result is an ensemble of structures (see [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29047011) for a comparison with crystallography). However, it is possible to see multiple structures for crystallography as well. [This](http://www.pnas.org/content/108/39/16247) paper on "Accessing protein conformational ensembles using room-temperature X-ray crystallography" describes limitations to the idea of crystal structures having one unique structure.

Comment: Does that mean: *using a ensemble-based model of DHFR* is using one conformation of DHFR (e.g. there might be multiple DHFR forms in E. coli, and the study used one of them)?